# Applescript to prepend and append text to existing textedit document

Tags: applescript

I am new to using applescript.  I would like to write a script to add text to an existing file.  Specifically, I would like to prepend/append a given document, e.g., prepend "Hello" [existing text in document] append "Goodbye."  I found this example:

```
tell application "TextEdit"
activate
set theDesktopPath to the path to the desktop folder as text
set file_URLs_content to "HEEEELLOOOOOO"
make new document with properties {text:file_URLs_content}
save document 1 in file (theDesktopPath & "file.txt")
close document 1
end tell
```

But, this is not quite right because I do not need a new document, and I want to specify the location of the text (at the beginning of the file, or at the end).

I am open to other solutions, as well.  Ultimately, I want to use the dictation command feature to run the script, perhaps via automator.  Many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

TextEdit is not needed to write plain text to disk.

`writeToDisk from theText into thePath given append:append` writes plain text to disk

Parameters:

• `theFile`: a HFS path
• `theText` the text to be written
• `with append`: append the text - `without append`: overwrite from the beginning of the text

```
set theFile to (path to desktop as text) & "file.txt"

set file_URLs_content to "HEEEELLOOOOOO"
writeToDisk from file_URLs_content into theFile with append

on writeToDisk from theText into thePath given append:append
    try
        set fileDescriptor to open for access file thePath with write permission
        if not append then set eof of fileDescriptor to 0
        write theText to fileDescriptor
        close access fileDescriptor
    on error
        try
            close access file thePath
        end try
    end try
end writeToDisk
```

If you prefer to write UTF-8 encoded text change the `write` line into

```
write theText to fileDescriptor as «class utf8»
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is very helpful.